# Hangfire Server not able to process recurring job for Process.Start(processstartinfo)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

I have an ASP.NET Core Web App that I am trying to use Hangfire on to schedule background jobs (Calling exe's). Everything works with jobs queued like the tutorials:

```
backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));
```

However, when I try to run:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("job3", () => Process.Start(process), $"*/{interval} * * * *");
```

[image]

I can start the process from the program just fine without Hangfire. Do I need to make a separate process to host the Hangfire server and make sure that process has System.Diagnostics? Or do I need to Serialize the data myself and pass it to hangfire differently?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the processStartInfo, I went ahead and made a class and method where I only passed an int id which was easier to get serialized I guess.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<JobRunner>($"Batch id {batchId}",x => x.RunBatchJob(batchId), $" */{interval} * * * *");
```